# Area of a concave quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

I was asked a question by an engineering friend recently and was not certain of how to solve the problem. I know there are (somewhat complicated) formulae that compute the area of a quadrilateral (convex or concave) in terms of the sides and a diagonal or an angle, but is there a formula for the area of a concave quadrilateral in terms of just the side lengths?

My intuition is that the side lengths do not uniquely determine the quadrilateral, but I cannot prove this either. If the sides were specified by points on a coordinate system, I feel like the lengths would produce slopes, hence, angles, but I am not even certain this is true.

I have two questions: are the lengths of the sides enough to specify the quadrilateral? What is the area of the resulting figure? Any insight helps.

Comment: `are the lengths of the sides enough to specify the quadrilateral` No. Think of square vs. rhombus.

Comment: But this quadrilateral is concave. Both a square and a rhombus are convex.

Comment: If the sides alone are not enough to specify a convex quadrilateral, why would that be any different for concave ones? For example, take something like [this](https://php.math.unifi.it/archimede/archimede/curve/immagini_meccanismi/m19q1.gif) and play with it to make infinitely many quadrilaterals having the same sides but different shapes and areas, both convex and concave.

Comment: Thank you! That answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

Having the lengths of the sides is not enough to calculate the area of a polygon (except triangle). But if you have the coordinates of the vertices then you are able to calculate the area. Here is how the formula looks like:
[image]

Comment: “Having the lengths of the sides is not enough to calculate the area of a polygon.” Yes it is, when $n=3$.